# Installing libyaml for ruby on a mac osX (Lion)

Tags: ruby, macos, psych

I am getting this error message:

```
"It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby."
```

I have tried entering this command: `rvm pkg install libyaml`

and I am getting this error message:

```
"Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/luke/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/luke/.rvm/src
Error running 'tar xmzf /Users/luke/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C
/Users/luke/.rvm/src ', 
   please read /Users/luke/.rvm/log/yaml/extract.log
Configuring yaml in /Users/luke/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/luke/.rvm/usr"  ', 
   please read /Users/luke/.rvm/log/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/luke/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/luke/.rvm/log/yaml/make.log

Database file /Users/luke/.rvm/config/packages does not exist."
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the extract.log and configure.log like the error message instructs? Perhaps post the contents to a gist (gist.github.com).

Comment: I did not. Reading that now. Thanks!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2640638

This is what I got when I opened extract.log. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Open a new terminal window and:

```
cd .rvm/src
sudo rm -rf yaml*
```

**(supply your credentials)**

```
cd ~
rvm pkg install libyaml
```

Comment: ``rvm package install libyaml`` for rvm 1.6.4

Answer (score 12):

The current release [was] LibYAML: `0.1.4 (2011-05-30)` [in 2012 when I answered this question].

Download the source package: `http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz`.

To build and install LibYAML, run

`$tar zxf yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz`

`$cd yaml-0.1.4`

`$ ./configure`

`$ make`

`$ make install`

OR just:

`$brew install libyaml`

Next,
`$brew install ruby`

Good luck.

Comment: I am getting this after the "./configure" step:

make  all-recursive
Making all in include
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in .
Making all in tests
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in win32
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
luke$


Also, I am not sure if it matters but $brew install ruby does not seem to work for me. I am using rvm to reinstall it. I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

- rvm remove 1.9.3
- download http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
- cp Downloads/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz .rvm/archives/
- rvm install 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

Installing ruby with rvm for mac osx, use autolibs to install libyaml and first uninstalling libyaml helps.

This worked for me:

```
brew uninstall libyaml
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.1
```