# I cannot install libyaml in Brew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails on Mountain Lion. It says that libyaml is a dependency for ROR. I go to run brew install libyaml and it tries to download http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz

Brew always returns with " curl: (7) couldn't connect to host"

This site no longer exists or is down. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I already tried brew update.

Comment: If you are using rvm you could try this solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392495/installing-libyaml-for-ruby-on-a-mac-osx-lion

Comment: That link works for me, by the way. How about you?

Comment: I think the site is back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. Apparently  my school blocks the URL's needed in the download process. Not ever a real problem.